Counting the number of handshakes

Every living person has shaken hands with a certain number of other
persons , prove that a count of  the number of people who have shaken
hands an odd number of times must yield an even number

Now I've seen an answer  here Number of people having shaken hands an odd number of times
However, I was wondering if there's a way to do this with counting
Here's what I was thinking :-
case 1) each person only shakes each other's hand once :- $c(n,2)$
Each person shakes each other's hand twice $2c(n,2)$ and so on
however, this doesn't take the cases into account where only a certain subset of people, say $r$ shake each others hands multiple times, say $\xi$
so the total number of shakes would be
$\sum_{i=1}^nn\left(c\left(n,2\right)\right)+ \xi c(r,2)$
however this still misses cases, so what do I do from here, how do I consider all cases ( For there are many, but finitely many such cases)
I have seen ways to approach this using vertices, however, I'd like to avoid that as I don't know vertices

Not sure I see the idea here.  The standard argument ignores the actual number of handshakes involving a fixed person and just considers its parity.  After all, what difference does it make if the value is $1$ or $10,413$?  All that matters is that both are odd.
